# Scipy sparse matrix become dense matrix after assignment

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

```
alpha = csr_matrix((1000,1000),dtype=np.float32)
beta = csr_matrix((1,1000),dtype=np.float32)
alpha[0,:] = beta
```

After initiation, alpha and beta should be sparse matrixes with no element stored there. But after assigning beta to the first row of alpha, alpha become non-sparse, with 1000 zeros stored in alpha. I know I can use eliminate_zeros() to turn alpha back to sparse matrix but is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Your title is wrong - it is still a sparse matrix; it's just not cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

When I copy your steps I get

```
In [131]: alpha[0,:]=beta
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: 
   SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a
   csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
   SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

So that's the first indicator that you are doing something that the developers consider unwise.

We could dig into the `csr` `__setitem__` code, but my guess is that it is converting your `beta` to dense, and then doing the assignment. And isn't automatically doing the `eliminate_zeros` step (either during or after the assignment).

Normally why would people be doing `a[...]=...`?  Usually it's to build the sparse matrix.  Zeroing out non-zero values is possible, but not frequent enough to treat as a special case.

It's possible for a variety of reasons to have 0 values in a sparse matrix. You could even insert the 0s into `alpha.data` directly.  That's why there are 'cleanup' methods like `eliminate_zeros` and `prune`.  Even `nonzero` applies a `!=0` mask

```
    # convert to COOrdinate format
    A = self.tocoo()
    nz_mask = A.data != 0
    return (A.row[nz_mask],A.col[nz_mask])
```

In normal sparse practice you build the data in `coo` or other format, and then convert to `csr` for calculations.  Matrix multiplication is it's strong point.  That constructs a new sparse matrix.  Modification of a `csr` is possible, but not encouraged.

====================

`alpha.__setitem__??` (in Ipython) shows

```
def __setitem__(self, index, x):
    # Process arrays from IndexMixin
    i, j = self._unpack_index(index)
    i, j = self._index_to_arrays(i, j)

    if isspmatrix(x):
        x = x.toarray()
    ....
    self._set_many(i, j, x.ravel())
```

So yes, it converts the RHS to a dense array before doing the assignment.