# How to delete the small none-zero values and increase the sparsity?

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large csr_matrix (46000*46000) ,but this matrix is very dense, its sparsity is about 0.05%. most of none-zero values are less than 1 ,I want to delete these values and increase the sparsity

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
cgc=sp.load_npz('/root/cg.npz')
print cgc.count_nonzero()                 #2115920056
cgc=cgc[cgc>1]                            #too slow
```

Comment: `and let it become a sparse matrix` - Do you mean one of the SciPy sparse matrices?

Comment: Yes,I want to drop most nonzero values and Increase sparsity of the matrix

Comment: You could perform masking to change the values of `cgc.data` inplace. That should be fast. But then you need to run the inplace `eliminate_zeros` method, which will be slower.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37674435/901925

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Zero the elements in-place, and then convert.This works on the array in-place to save memory and time, but changes your original array (which seems to be saved to disk anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem):

  ```
  cgc[cgc<1] = 0
  cgc = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(cgc)
  ```
- Build the sparce indices and construct the sparse matrix from them (doesn't overwite original, but is slow and memory-intensive):

  ```
  i, j = np.flatnonzero(cgc > 1)
  cgc_sparse = np.csr_matrix((cgc[i, j], (i, j)))
  ```

Comment: Thanks,but there are billions of none-values less than 1 in the matrix,so "cgc[cgc<1]=0" is very slow and inefficient

Comment: Slow is true, but I'm not so sure about "inefficient."

Comment: I say inefficient is compared to "cgc=cgc[cgc>1] "，just now I found an option "cgc.astype("int32")"，and I think there are other ways to solve this